# Proof using properties of real nos

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $a,b \ge 0 $ and $a^2 \lt b^2$ then $a \lt b$

I came across this and got lost!!!
Pls help me ...im sooo confused!
Hints or general steps please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple algebra ... Since $a^2-b^2\lt0 \implies (a-b)(a+b)\lt 0$. But since it is given that both $a$ and $b$ are $\ge0$, $(a+b) \ge 0$. So the only thing that remains now is $a \lt b$

Comment: no where have i assumed that $a \lt b$...

Comment: perhaps you have not seen what is given

Comment: Yes, you're right. +1 btw!